# Transfering long files with SSH to RHEL

Tags: ssh, filenames, remote, file-transfer

I am using SSH Secure Shell GUI to transfer some folders from Windows to a RHEL server, but one of the file inside the folders has a name which is too long and I can't shorten the name as it is some output of compilation process.

The transfer fails with no explicit message and it took me a certain amount of time to realize what the problem was, simply by repeating the drag-and-drop with subfolders until I have found the failing one.

If from inside the subfolder I manually drag the file to the server, everything works, however when I try to drag all the parent folder, the operation fails.

Where does this limitation come from and how can my problem be solved?

Comment: How long is the filename?

Comment: CurrencyInitializer$$anonfun$com$gottex$gottware$server$startup$initializers$impl$currency$CurrencyInitializer$$updateDepositEquivalentBonds$1.class

Comment: Actually, I should have asked you to include the length of the folder name as well.  Most likely you are running into a limitation or bug of the SSH client software you are using on the Windows side or of Windows itself, which would make this a Windows question unfortunately.  You could try another client, such as [PSFTP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: can you suggest any solution with a gui? :)

Comment: WinSCP or FileZilla should work, at least for testing.

Comment: Even with filezilla the transfer fails, with reason: "Could not start transfer"

Comment: with the difference that I can't even transfer it manually :(

Comment: You could try looking in the server logs if you have access to them.  See what's in `/var/log/secure`.  Do you know what internal method SSH Secure Shell GUI uses to transfer files: SCP, SFTP, FISH?  If you can't turn up anything in the server logs, then you need to figure out what's going on on the Windows side, but such questions don't belong here, so this should probably be migrated to Super User.